# How to change the path of Microsoft Office Soap Type Library in Access 2010?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-access, microsoft

[image]

I have OFFICE14 and OFFICE16 in Microsoft Share folder.
I have two questions:

1. As you can see the last few words in the path are cutout. How do I look at the full path here.
2. How to change the path of MS Office Soap Type Library.

Completely stumped by this because as you can see there aren't lot of options on the screen to edit the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you can see the last few words in the path are cutout. How do I look at the full path here.

You can’t the intention is to use the browse button and navigate to the folder. Office 14 is Office 2010, Office 15 is Office 2013, while Office 2016-2021 is Office 16 (with each being a multiple office 16 build release).

> How to change the path of MS Office Soap Type Library.

Remove the version that’s listed and add a different version using the browse button. There probably isn’t another version installed if you only have Office 2010 installed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would lean to Ramhound's explanation in one of the other answers.  This is a different take.

Your question about editing the path makes no sense.  This is a COM DLL and not a file you simply load.  To change the path, this file would need to be re-registered somewhere else.  Moreover, why on earth would you want to do this in the first place?

The Microsoft soap library you are referring to is called MSSOAP30.DLL.

On my machine, it is ACTUALLY located in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX64\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16" as I have the 64 bit version and not the 32 bit version.

Office 16 does quite a bit of trickery when it comes to paths.  If you look in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\vfs", you will see a number of folders that get "mapped in" as virtual folders when an office component loads.  For this reason, I don't think that even re-registering the DLL is a good plan.  It might be harmless.. in fact it *should be* harmless.. but I myself wouldn't do it unless I was willing to hose and need to re-install office.

Please provide more information for what you are trying to do and someone here can probably help you (perhaps even me).

Now, after having said all of that, I will answer your question.

### ***DO NOT DO THIS UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING! (and you don't)***

If you do indeed want to reference a different DLL and not that one, you need to use an application called `regsvr32.exe`.  Regsvr32 looks in a DLL for an entry point called "DLLRegisterServer" (for registration) and "DLLUnRegisterServer" (for removal).  It simply calls the function in the DLL to setup the registry with the proper paths to use the component.

If you are trying to replace one COM dll with a different version, you will want to run UNregister on the old one before running register on the new one.

- regsvr32 /u <path_to_old_dll>
- regsvr32 <path_to_new_dll>

The reason for doing the /u is because the functions DLLRegisterServer and DLLUnRegisterServer are *just code*, not some sort of automated process.  The old one might leave things behind that the new one doesn't clobber.  If there is no old one.. or it got deleted, it is fairly low risk simply to register the new one without the other step.

You need a lesson in COM to understand this and it is becoming more and more of a lost art.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation :)